# Pattern matching in Java for alphabets and numbers

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I am doing a simple pattern matching, which is not working. Please help

The string is:

```
The number *TER8347834SC* has problems.
```

The String contains a number *TER8347834SC* which may change with different messages, so i need to use regex to match this number while comparing the String. So while comparing String I am using the regex as `[A-Z0-0]` for *TER8347834SC* which doesn't match.

I know this is quite simple, but i tried many times, please help me in this.

Comment: `[A-Z0-0]` ??? I guess you mean  `[A-Z0-9]+` (i.e. range 0-9 instead of 0-0 as well as a string length of more than 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```
"\\b[A-Z0-9]+\\b"
```

Note that `\\b` word boundary is a much needed one.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, I had tried \\b, but did not use + in the end. So it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one:

```
([A-Z]+[0-9]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern should be like this **ONLY** if the message is always the same as you mentioned:

```
String pattern = "The number (.*) has problems.";
```

Comment: or more precisely:  String pattern = "The number \*(.*)\* has problems.";